# Astrolabe - I do not understand the data

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy

I have a problem. I read [this very simple](http://celebrating200years.noaa.gov/edufun/book/MakeyourownAstrolabe.pdf) document about the astrolabe.

I do not understand, however, the data that are included in the database (Sun observations):

http://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR?-source=J/A%2BA/375/614

more precisely:

http://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR-3?-source=J/A%2bA/375/614/table4

Additional information suggest very little to me.

Can somebody specifically suggest how to understand these data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click on the "Readme" link in table4, you will see that these measurements were made with a "modified Danjon astrolabe" and the purpose was to measure the apparent *diameter* of the sun, not just its altitude, which is the only thing you can measure with the simple astrolabe described in the NASA link.

The NASA type of astrolabe has been used for more than 2000 years - the ancient Greeks described them and how to use them. The Danjon astrolabe was only invented in the 20th century.

There are some pictures of a Danjon astrolabe [here](http://www.royalobservatorygreenwich.org/articles.php?article=1089), and a paper about how it works [here](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1958MNRAS.118..411D/0000411.000.html).